# Cannot install gedit plugin

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, plugins, gedit

I am new to Linux so please go easy on me. I am writing a program in c and formatting my code with vi editor and/or gedit is becoming a real pain in the butt; So, I need something to help me with the indentations of the code. I found this post here:

[How to get gedit to auto-indent code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245763/how-to-get-gedit-to-auto-indent-code)

- The best response,basically refers the asked question to a plugin for gedit text editor.
- I followed the instructions; ie., I created  .gnome2/gedit/plugins folders in the home directory and copied the extracted files there.
- went to edit, preferences,plugins, but the "Intelligent Text Completion" option is not there.

-I am running Ubuntu on virtual box.

Am I doing something wrong? OR is there something easier for me to do?

Comment: since your also going to want to compile/link/run the code, suggest apt-get install geany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per the gedit help contents,  use 'sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins'  However, I did not see any facility to enforce 'C' code formatting.

I would suggest using 'geany' which is available by: 'sudo apt-get install geany'

It comes with the facilities for many different languages, including one click compile, one click build, one click run, configurable formatting, and many other very useful programming features.

Comment: Your solution works greatly; it's exactly what I needed. I am using "Geany" now. Thanks for your help.